# How to catch data in react-redux when error trim is show?

Tags: redux, react-hooks, trim, kentico-kontent

I can't load post when I don't declared categories, but if I try to set default categories then I can't changes categories for another one? Somody have to Idea what to do?
useSelector - Redux.

```
 const catchTaxonomies = useSelector(
    state => ({
      catchTaxonomies: state.catchTaxonomies
    })
  );

let taxonomiesEqual =  catchTaxonomies.catchTaxonomies;
```

downloading data from Kentico based on categorie sent by catchTaxonomies from siedbar

```
const fetchArticles = categories => {
    client.items()
      .type("article")
      .containsFilter("elements.categories", [categories])
      .elementsParameter(["title", "image", "urlslug", "headline", "content", "pagination", "categories"])
      .getObservable()
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response.items);
        if(response.pagination.nextPage) {
          setLoadNewArticles(!loadNewArticles);
        }else {
          setLoadNewArticles(false);
        }
        setData(response.items);
        setLoading(!isLoading);
      });
  }
```

And I put this function to useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {  
      fetchArticles(taxonomiesEqual);
  }, [])
```

### Error message:

> filters.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: m.trim is not a function
>     at filters.js:171
>    at Array.map ()
>   at ContainsFilter.getParamValue (filters.js:170)
>     at url.helper.js:22
>     at Array.forEach ()
>     at UrlHelper.addOptionsToUrl (url.helper.js:20)
>     at QueryService.BaseDeliveryQueryService.getUrl (base-delivery-> > query.service.js:93)
>     at MultipleItemQuery.BaseQuery.resolveUrlInternal (base-query.class.js:57)
>     at MultipleItemQuery.BaseItemQuery.getMultipleItemsQueryUrl (base-item-query.class.js:93)
>    at MultipleItemQuery.BaseItemQuery.runMultipleItemsQuery (base-item-query.class.js:104)
>    at MultipleItemQuery.getObservable (multiple-item-query.class.js:234)
>    at fetchArticles (Main.js:33)
>    at Main.js:53
>    at commitHookEffectList (react-dom.development.js:18053)
>    at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:18080)
>    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
>    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
>    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
>    at commitPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:19706)
>    at wrapped (scheduler-tracing.development.js:177)
>    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:19759)
>    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:20332)
>    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21357)
>    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:21267)
>    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:21241)
>    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:21096)
>    at scheduleWork (react-dom.development.js:20909)
>    at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:21604)
>    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:21630)
>    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:21698)
>    at ReactRoot.push../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js.ReactRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:22011)
>    at react-dom.development.js:22163
>    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:21486)
>    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:22159)
>    at Object.render (react-dom.development.js:22234)
>    at Module../src/index.js (index.js:8)
>    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:781)
>    at fn (bootstrap:149)
>    at Object.0 (index.js:10)
>    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:781)
>    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
>    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
>    at main.chunk.js:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query fails because the second parameter of 'containsFilter' has invalid parameter. You need to pass a string array such as:

```
.containsFilter('elements.categories', ['category1', 'category2'])
```

Can you double check the value you get in your `categories` variable?

Comment: I create dynamicly object where is change taxonomies and load post ;)